# How to escape pipes in .screenrc for commands to run at startup?

Tags: bash, pipe, gnu-screen

I'm using [byobu](http://byobu.co)/screen, and I would like to have a new screen session default to containing a few windows set up specially for tailing a specific log file.

My `.screenrc` looks something like this (technically this is my `.byobu/windows` file):

```
chdir /home/matt/code/project/logs
screen -t 'logs' tail -F current.log

chdir /home/matt/code/project
screen -t 'errors' tail -F current.log | grep -A 3 "ERROR"

chdir /home/matt/code/project
screen -t 'project'

chdir 
screen -t 'bash'
```

My intention is to set up four windows in the new screen session:

1. A window titled "logs" which tails the `current.log` file
2. A window titled "errors" which tails the `current.log` file and greps for `ERROR`
3. A window titled "project" which starts in my project's main directory
4. A window titled "bash" which starts in my home directory.

However, the pipe in the `screen -t 'errors' tail -F current.log | grep -A 3 "ERROR"` command ends up being interpreted by screen literally, and thus my second window never appears.

How can I escape the pipe in this command to have it interpreted as I wish?

Furthermore, is there an easier way to setup screen/byobu to launch windows that are running (complicated) commands at startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the stuff command to simulate entering a command in the window and pressing enter to execute it. This has the nice effect of making it possible to break out of the tail command in the screen window without also killing the window itself.

Here is an example of what my .screenrc looks like to accomplish this; I've written up [a longer explanation on my blog](http://blog.mattnworb.com/how-to-setup-gnu-screen-to-tail-log):

```
screen -t 'errors'
stuff 'tail -F /var/ec/current.log | grep -A 3 "ERROR"^M'
```

(the ^M is entered by pressing Ctrl+V, Enter with your keyboard, not by actually typing caret and uppercase M)

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
screen -t errors bash -c "tail -F current.log | grep -A 3 ERROR"
```

The use of bash (or other shell) is required to prevent screen from giving a "file not found"-error, which will be the result if `bash -c` is removed from the above.

Comment: please add some explanation to your code to help others in the future

Comment: This seems to be a simpler answer, which uses known `bash -c` syntax and plays well in .screenrc

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with creating custom script and use it in your .screenrc - so you would have screen -t 'error' ./bin/current.log.sh

And tail -F ... in current.log.sh